# Media query not working for Samsung Galaxy Tab 4

Tags: android, html, css, ionic-framework

I'm trying to use a media query for a Samsung Galaxy Tab 4. What I'm reading from the internet is the width of the screen is 1280px. Now when I change the min-width to 1px, it works fine. The syntax I used for this is:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1280px) {
      #color {
         background-color: red;
      }
}
```

Comment: Have you set your viewport as: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`?

Comment: What you probably want to say is `max-width`. i.e. Apply these styles only upto 1280px screen sizes. Which covers your galaxy tab 4. Saying `min-width` means, starting at 1280px and beyond.

Comment: @AndyHoffman yes they are already set.

Comment: Changing it from min to max worked!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1280px) {
      #color {
         background-color: red;
      }
}
```

Comment: I want to start at 1280px.